# Getting exception while running Concordian test on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, concordion

**Getting the following exception while running the concordian test in Jenkins. 
Request to help me resolve this issue?**

**Stack Trace :**

```
target/surefire-reports java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:221)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:176)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:288)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:199)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:323)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:388)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:692)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:61)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:144)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:256)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:57)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:65)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:60)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:55)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:86)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
  at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103) 
  ... 4 more 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
  at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:221)
  at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:176)
  at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:288)
  at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:199)
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:323)
  at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:388)
  at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:692)
  at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:61)
  at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:144)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:256)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:57)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:65)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:60)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:55)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:52)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:80)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:164)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:86)
  ... 9 more
```

Last caused: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
So, you have error with checksum at file META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

Remove all:
Name: (your class name)
SHA1-Digest: (sha1)
Or regenerate file META-INF\MANIFEST.MF